# Проблема скраппинга веб сайта Python requests

Tags: python-3.x, requests

При выполнении кода,выдает совсем не HTML страницу.Что не так?Не на всех сайтах такое,а на некоторых.

```
response = requests.get('https://ytmonster.ru/')
print(response.text)
```

Может надо по другому как то? Что то вроде эмулирования браузера?

Comment: А что выдаёт, если не HTML?

Comment: У меня выдаёт HTML-страницу, так что непонятно о чём речь

Comment: @andreymal http://prntscr.com/m9axua

Comment: @DoubleMid это часть html-страницы, код из тега script, всё в порядке

Comment: @andreymal а не подскажете как полностью выгрузить?

Comment: @DoubleMid оно полностью выгружено, читайте ваш print внимательнее

Comment: @andreymal я имею ввиду то что на сайте же не только тег script

Comment: @DoubleMid и в response.text тоже есть не только тег script, ещё раз — читайте ваш print внимательнее. Если вас смущает то, что html-код не влезает в окно командной строки — читайте html-код по частям, например `print(response.text[:1000])`

Comment: Попробуйту вместо `print(response.text)` написать `with open('filename.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(response.text)`  и посмотрите что внутри файла 'filename.html'